# Is there a way to show progress in PIL (Python Library) while processing an image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, progress

I have some large photos, and want to show the progress (like numerical values from 0.0 to 1.0) while saving and/or modifying them.

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('wallpaper.png') # the image size is 150 MB
# doing some modification
image.save('modified_wallpaper.png', quality = 85) # the code is loading and will be executed without showing progress levels
```

Thanks in advance

I read through Pillow documentation, but never found something helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by modification? Does `tqdm` cover your needs? https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm

Comment: No easy way, unfortunately

Comment: @Anonymous tqdm would help to show progress when processing an iterator, e.g. when modifying dozens of different files. It won't get progress of saving a single image

Comment: No, there isn't. And, by the way, PNG is lossless, so setting the quality doesn't do what you expect.